# Wordpress - listing a hierarchy of categories with posts under each category

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

In wordpress, the following function will echo out a list of categories with the posts associated with each category underneath each category name.

This works fine, except for the fact that this produces a flat structure. Some of the categories are child categories other categories, and I'd like to be able to output a list with a structure that matches this (kind of like a site map)

Is anyone able to help me figure out how to modify this code to achieve this?

```
function posts_by_category() { 

 //get all categories then display all posts in each term
$taxonomy = 'category';
 $param_type = 'category__in';
 $term_args=array(
   'orderby' => 'name',
   'order' => 'ASC'
 );
 $terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
 if ($terms) {
   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
     $args=array(
       "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'caller_get_posts'=> 1
       );
     $my_query = null;
     $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
       <div class="category section">
         <h3><?php echo ''.$term->name;?></h3>
             <ul>
               <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
               <?php  endwhile;  ?>
             </ul>
       </div>
     <?php
     }
   }
 }
 wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet I found the other day [Hierarchical Category List with Post Titles](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/hierarchical-category-list-with-post-titles), should do the trick.

```
<?php
/*****************************************************************
*
* alchymyth 2011
* a hierarchical list of all categories, with linked post titles
*
******************************************************************/
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

 foreach( get_categories('hide_empty=0') as $cat ) :
 if( !$cat->parent ) {
 echo '<ul><li><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong></li>';
 process_cat_tree( $cat->term_id );
 }
 endforeach;

 wp_reset_query(); //to reset all trouble done to the original query
//
function process_cat_tree( $cat ) {

 $args = array('category__in' => array( $cat ), 'numberposts' => -1);
 $cat_posts = get_posts( $args );

 if( $cat_posts ) :
 foreach( $cat_posts as $post ) :
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
 echo '</li>';
 endforeach;
 endif;

 $next = get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent=' . $cat);

 if( $next ) :
 foreach( $next as $cat ) :
 echo '<ul><li><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong></li>';
 process_cat_tree( $cat->term_id );
 endforeach;
 endif;

 echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```